# Start interval after button click wicket

Tags: wicket

I'm trying to start an interval after button click.

```
button = form.add(new AjaxButton("button") {
  @Override
  protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
      AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior ajaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior = new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(5)) {
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

          @Override
          protected void onPostProcessTarget(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
              logger.debug("onPostProcessTarget");
          }

      };
      this.add(ajaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior);
  }
  });
});
```

The previous AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior does not start after button click. How can I make it start?

The wierd thing is if I add a new one like this after the previous block

```
button.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(5)) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onPostProcessTarget(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        logger.debug("onPostProcessTarget2");
    }

});
```

both of them start. But the last one also updates the dom which I don't want.

So all in all how can I start an interval after button click? (similarly to first code snippet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike regular form submission, ajax form submission (via an ajax button like you do here) is not going to re-render anything that you don't explicitly state you want re-rendered by performing `target.add(...)` on it.

What this means is that any changes you make to the component hierarchy or components themselves (like adding a new behavior) are going to stay in the back-end until you either update the individual components, or re-render the whole page.

In order to propogate any state changes in an ajax request call `target.add(this)` in your form submission. This will make wicket update the component and hence add the new behaviors of it to the front-end.

So given your example the code should look like the following:

```
button = form.add(new AjaxButton("button") {
  @Override
  protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
      AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior ajaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior = new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(5)) {
          private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

          @Override
          protected void onPostProcessTarget(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
              logger.debug("onPostProcessTarget");
          }

      };
      this.add(ajaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior);
      target.add(this);
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: So you are saying that if I remove `this.add(ajaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior);` and `button.add();` it will not re-render?

Comment: It will not re-render if you remove `button.add(secondBehavior)`. Because the second behavior is the one that carries the changes made in `AjaxButton` to the page.